# Bash script: Use string variable in curl JSON Post data

Tags: json, bash, curl

I want to send a json request and embedd a variable in the post data.
I did a little research and I came up with the single quotes around the variable.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    FILENAME="/media/file.avi"
    curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" —d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "Player.Open", "params":{"item":{"file":"'$FILENAME'"}}}' http://192.167.0.13/jsonrpc
```

Unfortunately I get some errors:

```
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '—d'
curl: (3) [globbing] nested braces not supported at pos 54
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 76
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 29 Jan 2014 19:16:56 GMT

{"error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error."},"id":null,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

Appearently there are some problems with the braces and the http answer states, that the command could not be executed. What's wrong with my code here? 
Thanks!

This is my `curl` version:

```
curl 7.30.0 (mips-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.30.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
Protocols: file ftp ftps http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL
```

Comment: This seems like a high probability candidate `curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '—d'`. Do a `man curl` and search for `--data`. Good luck.

Comment: The character before the `d` option seems to be some special typographic dash?

Comment: There seems to be a problem when my Variable has spaces. How can I put extra quotes around that?

Comment: Remove this single quotes directly around the variable, and it should be fine. You're trying to nest single quotes with no escaping or anything, so `$FILENAME` ends up being not surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903222/using-curl-to-send-json-within-a-bash-script  I ran into this same problem, and the answer below didn't help.  This however did.

Answer (score 22):

You can use:

```
request_body=$(cat <<EOF
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "Player.Open",
  "params": {
    "item": {
      "file": "$FILENAME"
    }
  }
}
EOF
)
```

However, if it is an option, use `jq` to generate the JSON instead. This ensures that the value of `$FILENAME` is properly quoted.

```
request_body=$(jq -n --arg fname "$FILENAME" '
{
  jsonrpc: "2.0",
  method: "Player.Open",
  params: {item: {file: $fname}}
}'
```

Comment: Just curious what is wrong with just `request_body=$(cat <<EOF ... EOF)`?

Comment: @smac89 I honestly could not tell you why I wrote `$(< <(...))` instead of `$(...)`. I might have been juggling a couple of different ideas in my head while writing this, which often results in a bizarre, complicated hybrid that I fail to simplify.

Answer (score 13):

My suggestion:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME="/media/file 2.avi"
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "Player.Open", "params":{"item":{"file":"'"$FILENAME"'"}}}' http://192.167.0.13/jsonrpc
```

The differences are hyphen in `-d` (instead of a dash) and double quotes around `$FILENAME`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to insert data from a file into a JSON property.
This solution is based on a really cool command called [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Below is an example which prepares request JSON data, used to create a CoreOS droplet on Digital Ocean:

```
# Load the cloud config to variable
user_data=$(cat config/cloud-config)

# Prepare the request data 
request_data='{
  "name": "server name",
  "region": "fra1",
  "size": "512mb",
  "image": "coreos-stable",
  "backups": false,
  "ipv6": true,
  "user_data": "---this content will be replaced---",
  "ssh_keys": [1234, 2345]
}'

# Insert data from file into the user_data property
request_data=$(echo $request_data | jq ". + {user_data: \"$user_data\"}")
```