# bash upload github api bash curl upload key doesn't work

Tags: bash, curl, github

Edit: I found this is a good answer, so this can probably be marked duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31214819/123594

I'm trying to upload a freshly generated deployment key to github via bash/ curl

Here's what I have: ($1 is my repo name, $2 is a suffix for my key name)

```
TOKEN=`cat /path/to/.github_token`
ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /path/to/key/id_rsa-www_$2 -q -N ""
KEY=`cat ~/projects/automatem/ansible/roles/accounts/templates/id_rsa-www_$2.pub`
echo $KEY
curl -u "myusername:$TOKEN" https://api.github.com/repos/jochendaum/$1/keys -d '{"name":"AUS1","key":"$KEY","read_only":true}'
```

As output I get:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC3rVUbDbhhHCD2q00T29UJRbMqbDdXOq8qwUlY/gOtvzxCu20nQHvGXG4L2FLWffO8V5TQH+e5Ei0G2TDfbjgiYH/BBBEd+agkZf6VHfWmOTG93D55Sse6LoVJNgXu1RICM3zS0CPQ31b05UUIw6AFjesntIh8EoaeftSm99CCxgLT3bRkSWkfSAng6VD6EwT1od+RMXxqOMpyJv0BeJaOELjJM8AAIIbjrcPaprAG3OixtJoYdBnUyK14srdmUjKmnJMFcrlFRPphzTnpjXZAFVIK1j7+Mh9UnNIKE5nlBL5Y5YtUkyy7ixIM/dCfu9tAyxufKjGz23Ug111WTmzB jochen@autodesktop2

{

  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "resource": "PublicKey",
      "code": "custom",
      "field": "key",
      "message": "key is invalid. It must begin with 'ssh-ed25519', 'ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp384', or 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp521'. Check that you're copying the public half of the key"
    }
  ],
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/keys/#create"
}
```

Its as if something is being cut off when the key is sent through curl

Comment: Try `echo '{"name":"AUS1","key":"$KEY","read_only":true}'` to see what curl sees: a literal `$KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the strange paths that you seem to use, but it might just be bad masking on your side, Bash won't expand anything inside single quotes.