# Curl: could not resolve host using riak

Tags: json, bash, curl, riak

I have this bash script that I'm using to read a csv file and insert my data in riak.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Set "," as the field separator using $IFS 
# and read line by line using while read combo 
while IFS=',' read -r Num_Acc senc catv occutc obs obsm choc manv num_veh
do
eval curl -i -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8098/riak/vehicule -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d {"Num_Acc":"$Num_Acc","senc":$senc,"catv":"$catv","occutc":"$occutc","obs":"$obs","obsm":$obsm,"choc":$choc,"manv":"$manv","num_veh":"$num_veh"}
done < vehicules_2016.csv
```

The issue is that I have this error and I don't kown where it could come from :

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: senc
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: catv
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: occutc
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: obs
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: obsm
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: choc
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: manv
curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: MochiWeb/1.1 WebMachine/1.10.9 (cafe not found)
Location: /riak/vehicule/NiuPBkgCFBaqUNhorovnBvix2ED
Date: Mon, 13 Nov 2017 11:43:08 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
```

I think the problem might be the json syntax.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enclose your data between either double quote `"` and escape inner double quote like `\"` or you can also use [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells) :

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=',' read -r Num_Acc senc catv occutc obs obsm choc manv num_veh
do
data=$(cat <<EOF
{
    "Num_Acc":"$Num_Acc",
    "senc": "$senc",
    "catv": "$catv",
    "occutc": "$occutc",
    "obs": "$obs",
    "obsm": "$obsm",
    "choc": "$choc",
    "manv": "$manv",
    "num_veh": "$num_veh"
}
EOF
)

curl -i http://127.0.0.1:8098/riak/vehicule \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d "$data"

done < vehicules_2016.csv
```

check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21440569/2614364)